# Serveless inference over multi-model endpoint - Amazon Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I created a model on Sagemaker using the following two options. I also specified the URI for the custom container under ECR as well as the root path for the model archives.
[image]

I am able to successfully created provisioned endpoint configuration however, in case of serverless, the following message showed up. Does this mean that it is absolutely not possible on Sagemaker to have a serverless multimodel endpoint?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that it is absolutely not possible on Sagemaker to have a serverless multimodel endpoint?

Basically with serverless you can deploy each model as a different endpoint and its cost effective as you pay only for usage. To answer your question technically you can't deploy multiple models on a serverless endpoint like you do with Multi model endpoints.